# Setting up Lync server on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, lync, instant-messaging, lync-2013

We have started a new startup, we have taken business email in hostgator.

Now we need to set up a Instant Messaging for our Startup. We have Microsoft Azure account and we want to set up Microsoft Lync in it.

How to set up Microsoft Lync Server 2013 in Microsoft Azure? If that is not possible how to set up Instant Messaging service for the startup.

Pl Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Rather then setting up your own servers which you have to maintain and understand how to be a Lync (Skype for business) administrator, you should consider Office 365 for business, check out the following page: http://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans

You will get email, storage, conferencing/im and full office for $5 per month per user.

Comment: What i thought is that would be costly and we have an azure account for free and therefore we can set VMs and install lync server on it. Can u pl help in this.

Comment: Actually Lync has it's own licensing costs per user, and you will find that it will cost you more.  You just can't setup a VM in azure load lync without a license and you need user licenses as well.

Comment: Office 365 Skype does not support any sort of useful PSTN connectivity at the moment. So if you intend to get actually phone calls on the thing....

Answer (score 0):

Deployment of production Exchange servers on Microsoft Azure virtual machines isn't supported.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj619301%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

It looks like the same for Lync servers